# Can PhpStorm v10 be installed on same machine as v2019.3

Tags: phpstorm

Can PhpStorm v10.0.4 (2015) be installed on same machine as v2019.3 or will they interfere with each other?

Comment: Yes they can be run in parallel : each major IDE version stores global (IDE wide) settings in separate folders. project-specific settings though are stored together with the project itself .. so may case some issues (loss of some settings) if you plan to open the same project in different versions often (especially when using such old IDE version).

Comment: @LazyOne you should put this as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can install and run them in parallel: no issues here.

Each major IDE version stores global (IDE wide) settings in [separate folder which is version specific](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544519-Directories-used-by-the-IDE-to-store-settings-caches-plugins-and-logs). It's quite common to have latest stable version (e.g. 2019.3) and EAP build of next major version (e.g. 2020.1 EAP) next to each other: working in stable version and be able to test something (preview new feature etc) in EAP build.

Project settings though are stored together with the project itself (in `.idea` subfolder; although you can workaround that if needed) and may case some issues (loss of some settings) if you plan to often open the same project in different IDE versions (especially when using such old IDE version as v10; simply because some settings can now be stored differently than 4 years ago).